# How to decompress an XZ file faster in Java?

Tags: java, android, compression, zip, xz

My SQLite db file of size 85MB is compressed using XZ format and its size has been reduced to 16MB. I use the following code (and a JAR provided by [XZ for Java](http://tukaani.org/xz/java.html)) to decompress it in Android Jelly Bean:

```
try { 
    FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(path + "myFile.xz");
    BufferedInputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(fin);
    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(des + "myDecompressed");
    XZInputStream xzIn = new XZInputStream(in);
    final byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
    int n = 0;
    while (-1 != (n = xzIn.read(buffer))) {
        out.write(buffer, 0, n);
    } 
    out.close();
    xzIn.close();
}
catch(Exception e) { 
    Log.e("Decompress", "unzip", e); 
}
```

The decompression is done successfully, but it takes more than two minutes to complete. I think this is very long because the compressed file is only 16MB and uncompressed file is only 85MB.

I wonder whether I have done something wrong with the code or there is a way to speed up this decompressing process.

Comment: what about this: https://www.sqlite.org/fts3.html , see compress option

Comment: Oh, I forgot to note that my sqlite db is already compact.

Comment: so you mean its already compressed? and even though xz shortens it to 20% of original size?

Comment: I mean my sqlite db was already compact (say with Compact Database, Firefox SQLite Manager). After this, XZ does a good compressing.

Comment: Nope. My db is an external one saved on sdcard. I'm happy with XZ, so I want to go for it.

Comment: I believe threads here would help.

Comment: @NiamhDoyle A question little off the track, but does XZ support decompression of `.7z` files??

Comment: Is there a way to get the percentage of completion?

Answer (score 2):

I think that there is little you can do to make this faster.  If it is taking 2 minutes to decompress 16Mb to 85Mb, the chances are that most of that time is spent in the actual decompression, and a significant part of the rest is in the actual file I/O ... at the physical level.

Certainly, there is nothing obviously inefficient about your code.  You are reading using a BufferedInputStream and decoding / writing using a large buffer.  So you will be doing the I/O syscalls efficiently.  (Adding a `BufferedOutputStream` won't make any difference because you are already doing large writes from a 8192 byte buffer.)

---

The best I can suggest is that you profile your code to see where the hotspots really are.  But I suspect that you won't find anything that can be improved enough to make a difference.

---

> I want to go for XZ because it has the best compression level in my case, which somewhat saves the downloading time... (with zip, the unzipping of this file takes only about 15 seconds!

Well, extra CPU time in decompression is the price that you pay for using a compression algorithm cranked up to the max.  You need to decide which is more important to your users: faster downloads, or faster decompression (installation?) of the database.

FWIW, ZIP decompression is probably implemented in a native library, not in pure Java.  It certainly is for Oracle / OpenJDK JVMs.

Answer (score 1):

The least you should do is wrap `FileOutputStream` int a `BufferedOutputStream`, there are very few instances where you should not use `BufferedInputStream`/`BufferedOutputStream`. Try it and see how long it would take now.

Comment: I mean instead of `FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(des + "myDecompressed");`, make it `BufferedOutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(des + "myDecompressed"));`

Comment: Thanks, but it's no luck. It still takes more than two minutes to decompress that file!

Comment: Try removing the write to file altogether and time it (so it only does read and decompression), if the time taken is still very close to what you get now, then it's the decompression that's taking all the time. in which case I guess you can either try to find another compression method, or maybe try to do the decompression using native C.

Comment: @NiamhDoyle Also, why do you want to compress it? So your app can fit into the 50MB APK limit? Depending on the sensitivity of the DB content, you can make the db an expansion download (http://developer.android.com/google/play/expansion-files.html)

Comment: Thanks, Kai. My app (and its db) doesn't fit the 50MB APK. In fact, I'm using .OBB expansion and this XZ file in one of the files inside the .OBB. I want to go for XZ because it has the best compression level in my case, which somewhat saves the downloading time... (with zip, the unzipping of this file takes only about 15 seconds!)

Comment: @NiamhDoyle I think for wifi & LTE download scenario 2 min decompression would be way longer than the extra download time :P Have you tried other compression methods to see their compression ratio and decompression time?

Comment: Well, regarding what you have helped and what @Stephen C mentioned, I may have to live with this pain!!! Have tried zip, gzip(2), lzma(2), xz...

Comment: @NiamhDoyle I suppose if the code spends quite some amount of time reading/writing, you can reduce time by running read/writing and decompressing in parallel. Right now first the CPU is doing nothing but wait for data, then file system is doing nothing waiting for decompressed data, etc. But personally if zip is that much faster I'd just go with zip and be done with it.