# Opening xz files with Apache Commons VFS

Tags: java, apache-commons-vfs

Is there a way to open XZ compressed files with Apache Commons VFS? It is not currently listed under the supported filesystems but I would imagine someone has tackled writing the necessary code already.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22421805/how-to-decompress-an-xz-file-faster-in-java

Comment: My question was specific to using XZ files within the Apache Commons VFS framework, whereas the linked question refers to opening them directly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to decompress an XZ file faster in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22421805/how-to-decompress-an-xz-file-faster-in-java)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So turns out it was simple enough to do. I ended up creating an open source project that adapted the internal Apache Commons VFS support for gzip and bzip2 and did the same for xz: https://github.com/asieira/vfs2-xz

All you need to do is include the JAR file in the CLASSPATH and URIs starting with `xz:` now work.